# Dynamically shrink an image with Google Images API, but do not enlarge

Tags: image, google-app-engine, image-processing, image-resizing

Google provides an excellent way to resize images dynamically; simply [append =sXX](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/images/functions.html#Image_get_serving_url) to the image URL. This is perfect if you want to shrink an image, but if the image is smaller than the size specified, it enlarges it, giving it a pixelated effect.

Is there an easy way to say "don't enlarge, only shrink" when using serving URLs with a specified size?

**UPDATE**

This functionality is now a feature request at GAE. **[Vote it up](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=5433) if you'd like to see it!**

Comment: Unfortunately, no this can't be done.  What is the need for this functionality?  There may a different way to solve this problem.

Comment: The need is for simplicity. Using the =sXX notation is incredibly simple, and allows for you to move on from displaying images to more important tasks. Without it, all of your resizing has to be done server-side and conditions have to be checked; it makes the code more complicated. That's a shame when there's an elegant solution like this notation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in my comments above, this isn't possible.

Although I have no use of the image framework I can see how your request would be useful.  May I suggest posting a Feature Request on the Google App Engines Issues BB?

After posting the request, update your StackOverflow question with a link to your Feature Request so that other users can +1 the request.

Here's the link to the GAE [Issues Page](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/list).  Although this is not a bug, you will need to click the New Issue button to request a feature.

Comment: Here is the issue: http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=5433

Answer (score 1):

What you could do is store the size of the image in the datastore so when you need the image to be a certain size, you can check in the datastore to see what size it is and add the =sXX accordingly.